# How to update attribute based on result of aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I am new to mySQL.
I want to update the order price of a table, based on the value of the retail price and the quantity of the product ordered. I have the following tables (simplified for this question):

`Products`:

```
ProductID
Retail_price
```

`Sales_orders`:

```
SalesOrdersID
Order_price //This is the derived attribute that I want to update when the below Sales_products table is updated.
```

`Sales_products`:

```
SalesOrdersID
ProductID
Quantity
```

The following code works in that I get the correct `Order_price` and it outputs in its own table. But I want to update the attribute `Sales_orders.Order_price`, not call out the order price in a table.

```
SELECT 
    sales_product.SalesOrdersID, 
    SUM(Quantity * Retail_price) as "Total price of order"
FROM 
    sales_product
    LEFT JOIN products ON sales_product.ProductID = products.ProductID
GROUP BY sales_product.SalesOrdersID
```

I've also tried a trigger, but this returns an error when I try to insert a new row in `Sales_orders`.

```
CREATE trigger find_order_price2
AFTER INSERT ON Sales_products
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    DECLARE price int;
SELECT
    sales_product.SalesOrdersID, SUM(Quantity * Retail_price) INTO price
FROM
    sales_product
        LEFT JOIN
        products ON sales_product.ProductID = products.ProductID;
UPDATE sales_orders
set Order_price = price;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Error returned :

> Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Hope somebody can help with this?

Comment: It could even be argued against doing this update at all, given that the value used for the update is just a derived value from other data in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a trigger, so I expect it to be using `new` or `old`.

This would usually be done incrementally:

```
CREATE trigger trig_sales_products_update_price
AFTER INSERT ON Sales_products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE sales_order so JOIN
           product p
           ON p.product_id = new.product_id
        SET so.order_price = so.order_price + new.quantity * p.retail_price
        WHERE so.SalesOrderId = new.SalesOrderId
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You can recalculate the entire value if you like:

```
CREATE trigger trig_sales_products_update_price
AFTER INSERT ON Sales_products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE sales_order so JOIN
           (SELECT sp.SalesOrderId,
                   SUM(sp.quantity * p.retail_price) as new_total
            FROM sales_products sp
                 product p
                 ON p.product_id = sp.product_id
            WHERE sp.SalesOrderId = new.SalesOrderId
            GROUP BY sp.SalesOrderId
           ) sp
           ON so.SalesOrderId = sp.SalesOrderId
        SET so.order_price = sp.new_total
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

However, triggers are usually done incrementally.

Remember that if you do this, you will also need `update` and `delete` triggers as well.  That is why it is simpler to calculate these values "on-the-fly" rather than maintaining them using triggers.

Comment: Thanks a million for your response. I will try out your solutions also.

Answer (score 0):

The following trigger code should get the job done:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE trigger update_sales_order_price
AFTER INSERT ON Sales_products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    UPDATE Sales_orders so
    SET Order_price = (
        SELECT SUM(sp.Quantity * p.Retail_price)
        FROM Sales_products sp
        INNER JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID  = sp.ProductID 
        WHERE sp.SalesOrdersID = so.SalesOrdersID
    )
    WHERE SalesOrdersID = NEW.SalesOrdersID;

END;
$$
DELIMITER;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mZG5dogWQUWkW4fqjWpqtP/0)**:

Consider the following layout:

Products:

```
| ProductID | retail_price |
| --------- | ------------ |
| 1         | 10           |
| 2         | 20           |
```

Sales_products:

```
| SalesOrdersID | ProductID | Quantity |
| ------------- | --------- | -------- |
| 1             | 1         | 10       |
```

Sales_orders:

```
| SalesOrdersID | Order_price |
| ------------- | ----------- |
| 1             | 100         |
```

Now, with the trigger in place, we insert a new record in the `Sales_items` table that relate to the same sales_order:

```
insert into Sales_products values(1, 2, 10);
```

After insert, here is the (updated) content of the `Sales_orders` table:

```
| SalesOrdersID | Order_price |
| ------------- | ----------- |
| 1             | 300         |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. I think I had some parts of this answer but your solution puts them in the right order, logic and syntax! I appreciate this and I'll try it out and get back with the result. Thanks again, very useful explanation also.